# How to have multiple values in django render to string

Tags: django

I have a email template that I want to pass values in to. This I achieve by the following code. I wish to know how to pass 2 variables that way

```
    subject = request.POST.get('inq_sub')
    message = request.POST.get('inq_mes')
    html_content = render_to_string('customer_inquiry.html',{'subject': subject})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass the message in render_to_string like:

```
html_content = render_to_string('customer_inquiry.html',{'subject': subject, 'message':message})
```

Inside customer_inquiry.html you can use your variable like this:

```
<h3>{{subject}}</h3>
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

Here is render_to_string from the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string